# How to define __new__ for Enum subclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I have a case where I have digit-only code values and some associated standard text. I have a number of fixed code sets I would like to define as enumerations where I can reuse the `__new__` method that attaches the associated text to the members (I am using `json` to dump these, so want the serialization to reflect the value and not the text), but I am unable to get it work.

Here is my attempt:

```py
import enum

class Code(str):
    def __new__(cls, code: str) -> None:
        if not code.isdigit():
            raise ValueError("code must be digits")
        return str.__new__(cls, code)

class CodeEnum(Code, enum.Enum):
    def __new__(cls, code: str, text: str) -> None:
        obj = Code.__new__(cls, code)
        obj._value_ = str(obj)
        obj.text = text
        return obj

class CodeSet1(CodeEnum):
    CODE_0001 = "0001", "Code 0001"
```

However, I get an `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'CodeSet1' object has no attribute '_name_'. Did you mean: 'name'?
```

Is there a way to resolve this such that I can reuse the `__new__` method in `CodeEnum` for each of my code sets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper definition for `CodeEnum` is:

```
class CodeEnum(Code, enum.Enum):
    def __new__(cls, code: str, text: str) -> None:
        obj = super().__new__(cls, code)
        obj._value_ = Code(code)
        obj.text = text
        return obj
```

The major difference is using `super()`.  `_value_` is a `Code` instead of just a `str` because it should be the same core type as the enum itself.

---

- Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.